# Android Activity listen to fragment when removed

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I need to listen my fragment when its removed by fragment it self from activity that handle fragment. How to do that?

I have one activity that extends ActionBarActivity and have layout like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments --> 
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/result_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/activity_googlecards_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e2e2e2"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

And onItemClik on my listview, it should show other fragment like this :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    mUpdateAdvertisementFragment = new UpdateAdvertisementFragment();

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

    extras.putString(TAG_ADVERTISEMENT_ID, advertisementData.get(position).getAdvertisementID().toString());                                                    
    mUpdateAdvertisementFragment.setArguments(extras);

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.result_search, mUpdateAdvertisementFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

and in my fragment i have a button that remove the fragment it self

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.back_button :
                // back button              
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
                break;
```

and here my fragment layout

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/back_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_back"
       android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
       style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" 
       android:text="@string/back_button_to_search_result"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My scenario : 
1. after user click back button from fragment
2. fragment removed by it self
3. return to activity
4. and sync data in listview from web server

Update :
I have sync function on my activity

```
public void syncData(){
        // init progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ListAdvertisementActivity.this, "", "Getting required data...", true);
```

So, i need to listen my fragment when its removed by fragment it self. How to do that? Should i need an interface to do that? Can you give me some snippet code? thanks.

Comment: can you make it a little clear why you need to listen my fragment when its removed by fragment it self. do you want to call the syncData yes?

Comment: Yup, i want to call syncData when fragment removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your fragment that you want to remove by itself

```
public void onDestroy(){

  super.onDestroy();
  ((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).syncData();
}
```

Comment: dose it go inside the sync or not ? can you put break point  on line dialog = ProgressD ... and check it?

Comment: its error `The method syncData() is undefined for the type FragmentActivity` and then i tried to change to `((Object) getActivity()).syncData();` and it cast error `The method syncData() is undefined for the type Object` any idea?

Comment: good news, dose activity of fragment have a syncData or this function is for another activity?

Comment: syncData is in an activity that handles a fragment. FYI. That activity extends ActionBarActivity.

Comment: brother try new answer !!

Answer (score 0):

try to call your `syncData` function in method  `onDetach()` of your Fragment :)